# Searching metadata attributes in opentext using REST API - POST

Tags: opentext

How to search for documents using REST API  Post method? I am looking to search by category attributes for a particular classification. I have not found any examples for REST API with POST method.

I get a "You have either not specified any search criterion at all, or one of your Livelink Query Language statements is incorrect. Edit the query by clicking an option in at least one list and/or correcting the statements that appear in the fields.\n" json response if I provide any search query in where clause in json body.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
https://myserver/OTCS/cs.exe?func=search&where1="Attr_12345_1":"Query"&outputformat=xml
```